# Автоматически ставится отступ сверху html, css

Tags: html, css

Собственно, на скриншоте сам и вопрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" >
        <img src="img/header3.jpg" class="img_responsive" >
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Откуда этот небольшой отступ сверху?</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
max-width: 100%;
line-height: 1.6;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #cccccc;
}

.img_responsive{
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

#content{
width: 960px;
height: 3200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

/**************************************************/
/*HEADER*/
/**************************************************/
#header{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#sm{
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 176px;
top: 16px;
}

#cross{
position: absolute;
float: right;
top: 116px;
right: 176px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в CSS, в теге `body` есть атрибут `line-height`, который устанавливает интерлиньяж (межстрочный интервал) текста со значением `1.6`. Уберите этот атрибут и пробела вверху не будет.

Comment: Убрал, отступ стал меньше, но он все равно есть

Comment: @user207012, Если вам нужно чтобы отступа вообще не было, тогда добавьте в CSS: `h1 {line-height: 0.7;}`

Comment: @user207012, если помог вам, отметьте как ответ

Answer (score 2):

Это стили, которые ставит user-agent. В Вашем случае - это margin у body в 8px.
Чтобы это преодолеть есть два варианта:

Не тру:

```
   body{
    margin:0;  
   }
```

Тру: 
   Использовать css файл для сброса всех дефолтных стилей, их существует много разных, почитать и выбрать можно [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/)

Comment: А что делать-то? Как убрать это?

Comment: Ваш ответ не верный, проверьте свой ответ в коде человека задающего вопрос